# Java fixed point arithmetic using byte

Tags: java, byte, fixed-point

I have some values that belong in [-1,1]. I don't need a lot of accuracy but I will need a LOT of those values. Now I'm more of a hardware guy so the solution came to me effortlessly: use fixed point arithmetic. I'm hoping to save memory by using the 8-bit Java byte type, which gives an accuracy of 2^(-7)=0.0078125. Is there a way already available to do this and take care of truncating/over(under)flow issues?

I also want to avoid as much computational overhead as possible, because those values are going to be into a lot of computation as well.

Thanks

Comment: What operations do you need to perform, and how do you want underflow etc to be handled?

Comment: Basically you'd just treat the number as if it were a float with the binary point between the sign bit and the remaining bits.  This doesn't quite give you +1.0 (how important is that?) but does give you -1.0.  Addition/subtraction is straight-forward, but you always have to scale after a multiply/divide (which should be carried out in at least 16-bit precision before shifting).

Comment: And be aware that the actual computations will be performed in wider precision -- byte is always widened to int on the stack -- so your local variables might as well be ints.

Comment: And also note that Java has "short" ints that are 16 bits but which otherwise play like bytes, so you can use shorts if bytes are too restrictive.

Comment: Since you must always carry out operations in wider form anyway, overflow detection is simply a matter of checking that the "insignificant" bits of the wider value match the sign bit.

Comment: I'm doing all 4 basic arithmetic operations with those values. 
Didn't know bytes were stretched to 32 bits for operation so I guess it isn't worth it.

Comment: It's still worth it in terms of storage (assuming the vast majority of your values are stored in byte arrays or in byte instance fields).  The widening/narrowing operations are quite quick, and you can take advantage of the extra width anyway to help with overflow detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way already available to do this and take care of truncating/over(under)flow issues?

It depends on how you want to deal with the these issues.  What you seem to be proposing is to treat the `byte` values as scaled values.  Now Java doesn't have any builtin support for scaled numbers, so you are going to have to do your arithmetic carefully ... taking care of truncation, underflow and scale adjustment yourself.

It can be done ... if you are careful.

---

But is it worth it?

First thing to consider is that a `byte` field or local variable takes exactly the same space as an `int` or `float` field ... 32 bits.  (Or potentially more on a 64bit machine.)

In fact you will only save memory if the bytes are actually members of a `byte[]`.

Then you have to ask yourself if the effort of achieving the space reduction is really worth it.  Have you *measured* how many of these scaled byte values there are going to be?  Have you compared it against the other memory usage in your application?  Do you even know how many of these scaled byte values need to be represented?

> I also want to avoid as much computational overhead as possible, because those values are going to be into a lot of computation as well.

There's the problem.  Arithmetic with scaled values will require extra instructions, especially if you want to detect overflow / underflow.  That will tend to make your application slower.

---

I would be inclined to implement the application simply using `float` which will take care of all of the overflow and underflow issues automatically.  Then run the application on real data to see how fast it is, and how much memory it uses:

- If both are acceptable, leave it alone.
- If memory usage is too great or speed are too slow, THEN look at ways to fix this.  If you decide to try the scaled number approach:

  - implement the key computations using `float` and `byte`
  - test to get the scaled arithmetic code corrected, and
  - benchmark both versions carefully to quantity the differences.

I can't predict what the results will be.  But I can tell you that a lot of people waste time optimizing code that doesn't need to be optimized.  Don't make that mistake - don't optimize prematurely.

Comment: I'm dealing with graphs, which supposedly should scale well. Each graph node would ideally require 200-300 values. I was thinking to accommodate as many nodes as possible but I guess the scalability isn't worth the trouble after all. I'll stick with float.

Comment: Good plan.  If scalability (with restricted memory) does turn out to be critical down the track, you can always revisit the implementation.

Comment: It's not universally true that byte instance fields actually occupy 32 bits.

Comment: @HotLicks - do you know of examples where is is not true?  (Lets exclude Java ME ... 'cos it is unlikely to be relevant.)

Comment: I know for sure certain that IBM iSeries Java, ca 2001, did not allocate 32 bits to a byte, because I was the one that didn't allocate them.  (And, by doing it this way performance improved about 5% on benchmarks, taking the top spot in the benchmark wars.)

Answer (score -2):

I understand your problem like this.  Following code gives performance also due to final variables.

final byte x = -1;
final byte y = 1;

Remember, with byte data types you must be little careful.

byte b1 = x*y;  gives error.  Do as follows.

byte b1 = (byte) (x*y);